# VLCJ Returning Incorrect Duration

Tags: java, swing, vlc, vlcj

I currently have a VLCJ player recording and displaying a stream, the stream is looping through a ~2min video, the display works fine and the file is constructed. No real errors appear aside from ones that can be ignored such as:

- `Timestamp conversion failed for xxx: no reference clock`
- `Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmeg`

Although when I go to replay the recording that I just made, the duration displayed is incorrect. For a recording that is ~15 seconds I could get 1 hour displayed, it is completely random.

I believe that this has to do with something in the IFrames and VLCJ not knowing exactly where it is, just guessing. The issue happens when the streamed video loops, i.e. when the streamed video reaches the end and then repeats itself, the new recording will result in a bad duration time.

Is there anyway to set the recorded time externally via a sperate timer that tracks how long the video was actually recorded, or possibly a option inside of VLCJ I can set?

Verisons:
VLCJ 4.7.1
VLC 3.0.7.1
Rhel 7
Java 11.0.10

I am using a swing application.

Comment: *No real errors appear aside from ones that can be ignored such as:...* (both of which refer to timing issues). Does that not raise concerns?

Comment: They are known errors which are typically ignored or silenced. @g00se

Comment: This could be a VLC issue, I just recreated the same issue with the VLC application. Using the same stream of a video repeating indefinite, connect to the steam and then record past the point in which the stream video repeats. After loading the recorded video, it had an incorrect duration.

Comment: You say vlcj is recording the stream, how are you stopping the recording? To properly close out the recording you must both stop the media player, and release it. On the other hand, if VLC itself results in the same issue, it's probably something else wrong.